# Proper multitasking for android

Tags: java, android

Hi im developing an android application and im wondering how i make the app use less CPU while backgrounded. For example, my application pauses once it loses focus but the cpu usage is still 50%

Edit

```
 while (!pause) {
             Canvas c = null;
             try {
                 c = sHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                 synchronized (sHolder) {
                     doDraw(c);
                     powerUps();
                 }
             } finally {
                 if (c != null) {
                     sHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                 }
             }
         }
```

Then when you pause and resume it just changes the pause variable

Comment: It sounds like you have a busy wait that's spinning and eating the cpu.

Comment: Can we see the code on what you are doing when you pause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, you should not be looping at all while your app is paused.

See [this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) for more details about the "proper" lifecycle of an android app.

Also note that with any busy loop design your app will be using 100% of the CPU - I'm not sure if starting a loop from the `onResume()` method is correct; my instinct is to have each iteration of your loop performed by a separate call initiated by a call to `Handler.post()`, with the last statement re-posting the next call.  Otherwise, the application's main thread will be starved, right?

Maybe something like this:

```
void iterate() {
     Canvas c = null;
     try {
         c = sHolder.lockCanvas(null);
         synchronized (sHolder) {
             doDraw(c);
             powerUps();
         }
     } finally {
         if (c != null) {
             sHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
         }
     }
     this.handler.post(this.iterateRunnable);
}

void onResume() {
    this.handler = new Handler();
    this.iterateRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() { iterate(); }
    };
    this.handler.post(this.iterateRunnable);
}
```

Comment: ohhhh and then on the onPause() you just remove callbacks for handler?

Comment: actually wait my class uses a runnable so how would i implement this usingth run() method

Comment: I meant `Runnable` instead of `Runner` - did I mention I didn't test this?  And yes - `this.handler.removeCallbacks(this.iterateRunnable);` should be done in `onPause()`.